# UDP Socket Programming in C, printf not working after calling recvfrom()?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am working on a project regarding socket programming in c and java, using UDP and TCP (separately of course). My UDP server is Java and my UDP client is in C. I have encountered an issue where, after I call recvfrom(), methods such as printf and fprintf are not actually printing everything. I also tried fflush. Here is that section of code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int sockfd, portno, n;
   int serverlen;
   struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
   struct hostent *server;
   char *hostname;
   char buf[BUFSIZE];
   int GID = 9;

/* check command line arguments and extract port numbers */
   if (argc != 4) {
     fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s <hostname> <port> <myport>\n", argv[0]);
     exit(0);
   }
   hostname = argv[1];
   int serverPort = atoi(argv[2]);                                                 
   int myPort = atoi(argv[3]);
   int portRange = (5 * GID) + 10010;
   if (myPort < portRange || myPort > portRange + 4) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Port range\n");
     exit(1);
   }

/* socket: create the socket */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sockfd < 0) 
     error("ERROR opening socket\n");

 /* gethostbyname: get the server's DNS entry */
   server = gethostbyname(hostname);
   if (server == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host as %s\n", hostname);
     exit(0);
   }

/* build the server's Internet address */
   bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
   serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
   serveraddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);

/* create a message */
   bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
   buf[0] = 74;
   buf[1] = 111;
   buf[2] = 121;
   buf[3] = 33;
   buf[4] = (myPort >> 8);
   buf[5] = (myPort & 0xFF);
   buf[6] = GID;

/* send the message to the server */
   serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);
   n = sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, 
     serverlen);
   if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR in sendto\n");

   bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);

/* print the server's reply if buf[6] != 0*/
   n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, 
      &serverlen);
  //ERROR OCCURS AFTER RECEIVING

   if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR in recvfrom\n");
   if (buf[6] == 0 && buf[7] == 1) {
     printf("ERROR: no magic number\n");
     return 0;
   }
   else if (buf[6] == 0 && buf[7] == 2) {
     printf("ERROR: incorrect length\n");
     return 0;
   }
   else if (buf[6] == 0 && buf[7] == 4) {
     printf("ERROR: port number out of range\n");
   }
   printf("%.*s\n", strlen(buf), buf);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is 'BUFSIZE'?

Comment: Is your received buf null terminated?

Comment: 'bzero(buf, BUFSIZE)', then 'n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf)....', 'recvfrom nothing at all'.  All strlen() calls in network code are hugely suspicious and likely to be wrong.  99% of all C network code posted to SO that has any strlen in it is wrong.

Comment: recvfrom() has length specified as "strlen(buf)"... right after you cleared it out with a bzero()....

Comment: Another large percentage  of all C network code posted to SO that has any 'printf("%s...' in it is also suspicious:(

Answer (score 2):

Usual problem. You're ignoring the count returned by `recvfrom()`:

```
printf("%.*s\n", strlen(buf), buf);
```

should be

```
printf("%.*s\n", n, buf);
```

NB your `recvfrom()` call is also incorrect. It should be:

```
n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, 
  &serverlen);
```

and if `n < 0` you should not enter the following if-else chain.